# Delay running of python script on boot until desktop is finished

Tags: python, boot

I tried simply editing the autostart file to run a Python script on boot, but it runs with errors, I assume becasue the desktop hasn't completed. Can someone tell me how I would launch a script with a delay?

Comment: Have you looked at this http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=43509

Comment: Yes, It works partially as mentioned in my post, but pretty sure I need a delay BEFORE I execute my script.

Comment: What is the exact error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do approximately this:

1. `crontab -e`, add a line

   `@reboot /home/pi/bash_script`
2. inside the bash script write the following

   `#!/bin/bash`

   `/bin/sleep 100 && /usr/bin/python /home/pi/blah.py`

where `blah.py` is your script you want to run with a delay.

Comment: don't I need to do a chmod on the script as well to make it executable?

Comment: ok, I have another issue with tKinter, if I simply run my script from LXTerminal it works, but if called via a cron job get _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Comment: well, set the environment variable DISPLAY and it will run perfectly